# Bicycle with 1 tire with Presta valve and 1 with Schrader valve

Tags: tire, valves, presta

One simple question: I have a mountain bike that has 2 tires with schrader valves. I bought a new tube with a presta valve by mistake.

Do you see any issues with replacing one of the tubes that had a schrader valve with a tube which has a presta valve and keeping the bicycle with one of each, or is this not recommended?

Comment: You can supposedly get a bushing that adapts a Presta valve to fit a Schraeder hole.  However, I've never seen one and they don't pop up readily on Google.

Comment: I've been using Presta valves in Schrader holes for years with no issues.

Comment: See also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-use-a-presta-tube-in-a-schrader-rim

Answer (score 5):

I swapped out both tubes on my mountain bike with Presta (less chance of crap getting in to the valve and it means I can carry the same CO2 inflator as I do on my road bike) and got the bushings - once they were in I've had zero issues with the valve stem. I'd definitely recommend putting one in since there's the chance that the valve stem could rub against the edge of the hole or the tube could even prolapse through the hole.

I have two of the [Presta to Schrader](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_9?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=presta%20to%20schrader%20adapter&sprefix=presta%20to,aps,146) adapters, mostly in case my CO2 inflator dies and I need to try and fill from a gas station (it happened once and I didn't have 'em). Just walk into your favorite B&M store and they'll probably have 'em in a container on the counter. I think I paid just over a dollar apiece. If you're really concerned about losing it you can screw it onto the Presta valve and leave it there; just make sure the valve is screwed shut before you thread the adapter on.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be fine with one of each kind of valve. Supposedly there's some increased risk of valve damage to the presta because it doesn't fit the schreader hole, but I've never seen it happen. Just keep your lockring on.

Comment: Be careful not to tighten the lockring too much as doing so will pull the tire through the hole.  You can also get grommets to make the holes smaller so that the presta valve will be more snug in the schrader sized hole. http://www.amazon.com/Pyramid-Sunlite-Bicycle-Rim-Grommet/dp/B000AO9QX8