# how to use "smart valve" pumps?

Tags: tire, pump

i got one floor pump with a so called "smart valve". it came with no instructions whatsoever. and I'm not smart enough to use it...

I tried it on both type of tire valves, and no matter what i do, it never press the internal valve mechanism to allow air in.

it is similar to this one:

[image]

How should i use it? do i have to turn something on the tip to adapt to either type of valve?

Comment: This is what I call an "agnostic" pump head -- it doesn't care whether the valve is Schrader or Presta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have [a pump](http://www.filzer.com/products.php?id=87) with what looks like an identical head.  Here's the [instruction pdf](http://www.filzer.com/img/products/87-instructions1.pdf) that they provide. The instructions provided are as follows.

1. Remove the dust cap from the tire valve.
2. For Presta valves, unscrew locking nut at the 
   end of the valve.
3. Wipe off any mud or dirt from the outside 
   surface of the valve stem; this ensures the pump's 
   Clever Head will work properly.  Also, release 
   some air from the tube by pressing the air release 
   tip on the valve to clean its inner parts.
4. Press the Clever Head on to the Presta or 
   Schrader valve stem as far as it will go and open 
   the thumb lever to the locked position.
5. The pressure gauge has a red arrow on the 
   bezel that you can rotate to the desired pressure 
   for easier reading.
6. Infate your tire by lifting the pump handle up 
   and pressing down.  Do not over pressurize tire; 
   see side wall of tire for maximum pressure value.
7. Use the pressure release valve to lower and 
   adjust tire pressure.
8. Move the thumb lever to the unlocked position 
   and remove the Clever Head from the valve stem.
9. For Presta valves, tighten the locking nut at the 
   end of the valve.
10. Replace dust cap

For presta valves, I usually don't undo the locking nut the entire way, as I've had problems with them bending and snapping.  Only undoing it half way seems to prevent this for the most part. Also, After I've mounted the pump in step 4, I press the air release button. If you hear air coming out, then it ensures the pump head is seated properly.

Comment: "Press the Clever Head on to the Presta or Schrader valve stem as far as it will go" hum. maybe because my Schrader tire is completely flat i can't press it enough for it to "work"?

Comment: This is probably the issue.  Try pushing against the tire with your hand to stop the valve from going back through the rim.  Presta valves have a nut to prevent this. Also, if you have presta valves, you have to have a fair amount protuding out of the rim to get the pump head seated properly.

Comment: Also, you should be able to test it on an unmounted tube without the tire and rim to worry about to ensure that there isn't some kind of defect with the pump.

Comment: yep. the unmounted tube did the trick. i measured how deep it has to go (almost the entire thread have to disappear) and then it can fill the tire. it was more trouble than it was worth it to try to insert it on the empty tire since it has MTB rubber... i just pumped a little with my hand pump.. debating if i will keep this floor pump or return it. it seems practical but i leave my tires empty pretty often. maybe it is a good motivator to not to :)

Comment: You may want to switch to using presta valves. See [this question](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-use-a-presta-tube-in-a-schrader-rim) for more information on doing that.

Comment: i will, and all my spare tubes are presta. but there is no reason to trhow away a perfectly good scheader tube just because it is annoying to pump :) so i'm running with both for now, until i get a flat.

Comment: I have just used followed the instructions. Fantastic guide.would recommend to anyone who is struggling. I have "Presta" valves. It's so simple when you know how!