# Tube compatibility for given tyre dimensions

Tags: tire, innertube

[image: new tube that I got]

My tire says: 700x40c  40-622 , is the tube in the picture a perfect fit?

Comment: One might note that the tube lists a width range from 40 to 62, with your tire on the extreme end of that range.  You could try to find a different brand/style that places your tire in the middle of it's width range, but that's being a bit obsessive.

Comment: As Daniel R Hicks said, there are better fits. For example Schwalbe’s No. 17 instead of your No. 19. The No. 17 is from 28-622 to 47-622 and weighs 150g instead of 220g.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your rim is drilled out for a Presta valve, this tube should be suitable. If your rims are deep (you would know if you had them), you may need a valve extender.

If you have a rim drilled for a Schrader valve (kind on a car tire), it is not recommended (if you want to use it, you should use a valve grommet as noted in [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-i-use-a-presta-tube-in-a-schrader-rim)) since the larger hole may allow for some damage to the tube, or better yet, buy a tube with a Schrader valve.

A Presta valve rim is 6 mm, Schrader is 8 mm.

Comment: Rim is drilled for presta. ThankYou for the answer :)